# Set global variables in function from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, global-variables, global

#### The problem:

I have a dictionary of keys and values:

```py
param_dict = {
    'VAR1' : 'abcd', 
    'VAR2' : (1, 1),  
    'VAR3' : 10.0
}
```

I want to write a function that takes in such a dictionary, and will set each key-value pair as a global variable.

#### What I have so far:

I have already figured out how to create global variables from my dictionary (as described in a number of answers to [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)). I run into problems only when trying to write my code (shown in the cell below) as a **function**.

```py
# Set defined values as global variables
for k, v in param_dict.items():
    exec(k + '=v')
```

You can see that each dictionary key is now the name of a global variable, and each dictionary value is the corresponding value:

```py
print(VAR1) # Prints the value of the global variable VAR1
```

But I don't know how to accomplish the same thing with a function, since placing all my code within a function will result in the creation of local variables, not global variables.

```py
def make_globals(param_dict):
    # Set defined values as global variables
    for k, v in param_dict.items():
        exec(k + '=v')

make_globals(param_dict=param_dict)

print(VAR1) # Returns a NameError
```

I know you can set global variables from within a function using `global` (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171780/global-variable-declaration)), but this method requires the name of the variable to be hard-coded into the function itself (at least as far as I can tell). This doesn't work for me since my global variable names can vary and I'm looping through multiple key-value pairs that I want to use as global variables. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```py
def make_globals(param_dict):
    # Set defined values as global variables
    for k, v in param_dict.items():
        vStr = f'"{v}"' if isinstance(v, str) else f'{v}'
        exec(f'{k}={vStr}', globals())

param_dict = {
    'VAR1' : 'abcd', 
    'VAR2' : (1, 1),  
    'VAR3' : 10.0
}

make_globals(param_dict=param_dict)

print(f'VAR1 is {VAR1}')

for k in param_dict:
    print(f'{k} is in globals()') if k in globals() else print(f'{k} is not in globals()')
```

Output:

```
VAR1 is abcd
VAR1 is in globals()
VAR2 is in globals()
VAR3 is in globals()
```

One key point is to pass `globals()` as an argument to `exec()`. I also made some changes to the strings you were passing into `exec()`.

**UPDATE**:

Here's what the first argument passed to `exec()` looks like:

```
VAR1="abcd"
VAR2=(1, 1)
VAR3=10.0
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the `vStr = f'"{v}"' if isinstance(v, str) else f'{v}'` line added to the function?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show what the string passed to `exec()` as its first argument looks like. As you can see, for VAR1 we have `VAR1="abcd"`, which is how you would normally initialize a variable to a string value. The way I got the quotes in was by having the `isinstance()` check to special case the use of quotes if the type of the value in the dictionary is `str`.